# How would I only work with one row to get quantiles of that specific row in "R"

Tags: r, csv, vector, subset, quantile

I want to get the top 5 and 10 percent + bottom 5 and 10 percent of a data set but for a specific row "TOTINCP"

**Current Code:**

```r
library("tidyverse")
data1 <- read_csv("1986Census.csv", col_names = TRUE)
attach(data1)
ls(data1)

dropped <- subset(data1, 26 <= AGEP & AGEP <= 64 & (TOTINCP >= 0 & TOTINCP <= max(TOTINCP)) & MARSTP != 1 & MARSTP != 5)

#male and female after dropped observations
male <- subset(dropped, SEXP == 2)
female <- subset(dropped, SEXP == 1)
incomeMale <- c(male, TOTINCP) 
quantile(incomeMale, 0.05,0.10,0.95,0.90)
```

`incomeMale <- c(male, TOTINCP)` <<<< this line is meant to get me all my TOTINCP values in a vector so I can go through that and get the quantiles but what it goes through my entire male dataset and does that for everything... I need the male part as I am not trying to get the quantiles for the entire dataset just the males.

I've tried making `incomeMale` a subset but it does the same thing, does anyone have. solution? Thankyou!

Comment: (1) Please never include `rm(list = ls())` in questions on SO. (2) It's typically best to reduce the problem with unnecessary code. In this case, `setwd` and `read_csv` do us no good, as we don't have access to your computer (nor should we :-). (3) Side-note: generally the use of `attach(.)` is ***strongly discouraged*** as it often leads to many problems. While its use adds a little utility/convenience, it introduces the potential for many problems and does not encourage a better understanding of R's structures.

Comment: Further, since we don't have your data, it might be harder to really help. It's great that you've included this code (most of it :-), please improve it with sample data (preferably from `dput(x)` where `x` is a representative and sufficient sample, we rarely need all columns and all rows).

Comment: in the code I just want to extract one specific rows values from the subset ```male```

Answer (score 0):

All I had to do was go into the `male subset` at list position of `TOTINCP` and put all those values in a numeric vector.

```
#male and female after dropped observations
male <- subset(dropped, SEXP == 2)
female <- subset(dropped, SEXP == 1)

#male bottom and top earners
incomeMale <- c(male[["TOTINCP"]])
quantile(incomeMale, c(0.01,0.05, 0.10,0.95, 0.99))
```